# How do I position to a particular fragment when using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am creating *detail* fragments from an ArrayList of objects, the ArrayList is a representation of a ListFragment. I am using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter to manage each detail page (fragment). Here's the code for my FragmentActivity's  FragmentStatePagerAdapter inner class

```
public static class DetailPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public DetailPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.e(Constants.TAG, "DetailPagerAdapter creating DetailFragment - item " + i );
        }

        Fragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
    // get object from outer class ArrayList
        Object fobject = detailslist.get(i);
        final Detail fDetail = (Detail)fobject;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DetailFragment.ARG_POSITION, i + 1);
        args.putString("detailTitle",fDetail.getDetailName());
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // object collection same size as list
        return detailslist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        return "Position #" + (position + 1);

    }
}
```

This creates all the detail fragments but it always shows the user the first ListFragment entry. I can swipe forwards and backwards OK. If the user selects an an item from the ListFragment and if that item is in the middle of the list I want to position to that detail object instance. I also want the user to be able to swipe back and forward to the other detail pages. I pretty sure I need to use the FragmentManager transaction methods but I not sure how to use it when using a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Anybody got any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ViewPager.setCurrentItem()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem%28int,%20boolean%29).